# How to make all cells in ag grid editable on click of a button

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

I am able to make all configured editable columns as editable but on focus, other cells change to view mode.
access the below link and click on start editing, all cells will change to edit mode. then start editing(typing) in a cell. now other editable cells in different rows will change to view mode.
can I retain editable mode of cells in other rows?
code to make rows editable:

```
onBtStartEditing() {
    this.gridApi.setFocusedCell(0, "make");
    this.gridApi.forEachNode(node => {
        this.gridApi.startEditingCell({
          rowIndex: node.rowIndex,
          colKey: "make"
        });  
    })
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/XbGLPZmD7pWnhd9O20iY?p=preview

I tried calling stopEditing(true) on cell focus but this changes this edit mode then immediately to view mode and infinitely calls the method.

I tried to call startediting on stop editing but this executes infinitely and web page crashes.

Answer (score 1):

moved out from using the ag grid edit feature and implemented edit like feature using the cell renderers swapping between view and edit mode.
had to manually implement tabbing, validations, regex restrictions